# How to rename subheader in TYPO3 CMS backend

Tags: typo3, backend, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

How can I rename a TYPO3 CMS backend field for authors? i.e. the mentioned field for content-elements of csc_styled_content?

Answer (score 5):

In general, overriding label names can by done with Page TSconfig in the backend. The following example modifies the label of the `subheader` field.

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        subheader.label = My new Label-Name
    }
}
```

There are two way to configure that adjustment in TYPO3.

1. Type your configuration changes directly to the **page settings » resources » TypoScript Configuration » Page TSConfig** (see the screenshot below)

   [image: where to add the TypoScript Configuration]
2. as an alternative you can store that configuration directly in the file system - either in your custom extension (e.g. at `typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Configuration/TSconfig/labels.t3s`) or with a similar name in the global file storage (e.g. `fileadmin/templates/configuration/...`)

That's basically it to provide custom labels for any database table in the TYPO3 backend. Find more aspects that can be adjusted in the accordant [Page TSconfig documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename a field of an extension like **tx_news** you could do it this way.

```
TCEFORM {
    tx_news_domain_model_news {
        title.label = Your New Label
    }
}
```

Now there are two ways to get this to work:

- Put it in *Page TSConfig* of the page settings

OR

- Load it with your extension from a file (e.g. `EXT:my_extension/Configuration/pageTSConfig.typoscript`). For that you have to import this script by `EXT:my_extension/ext_localconf.php`!

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
 '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_extrension/Configuration/pageTSConfig.typoscript">');
```