# How to edit: TypoScript Configuration » Page TSConfig?

Tags: typo3, backend, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 (using ver: 6.2.11) and I want to do the exact thing as mentioned in: [Rename the subheading in backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094786/how-to-rename-subheader-in-typo3-cms-backend). The problem is that I simply could not find navigation link to reach the specified destination *page settings » resources » TypoScript Configuration » Page TSConfig*. Either it is not showing or I am not at a right start page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit properties of the page like shown on below screenshot, if this tab/field is unavailable for you that means, you haven't proper permissions and need to ask to do this change the *full* admin.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also include pageTS config and UserTSConfig by using extension in ext_localconf.php with:

```
<?php

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addUserTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:typo3_template/Configuration/TypoScript/userTsConfig.ts">');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:typo3_template/Configuration/TypoScript/pageTsConfig.ts">');
?>
```

Hope it would be helpful for TYPO3 Users!

Comment: Thanks @Piseth for the post.