# How do I exchange the default RTE CK Editor preset of TYPO3 with the full preset of the RTE CK editor?

Tags: typo3, rich-text-editor, rte

How do I exchange the default RTE CK Editor preset of TYPO3 with the full preset of the RTE CK editor? I don't have a file called page.ts or sth. like this.

Answer (score 1):

A configuration with all function can be found in `typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Full.yaml`.

So, you have only to load this as default for RTE fields.

[Rich Text Editing in TYPO3 with CKEditor (rte_ckeditor) - Configuration Presets](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Concepts.html#configuration-presets) shows the following example to be put in `LocalConfiguration.php`, `AdditionalConfiguration.php` or within `ext_localconf.php` of an extension:

> $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/master/en-us/Configuration/Examples.html#how-do-i-use-a-different-preset is mentioning that I have to add "RTE.default.preset = full" to the Page TSconfig. But they aren't mentioning where exactly to put it within the file.

Comment: [Page TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/Index.html) can be set via editing a page in the backend.
["How to edit: TypoScript Configuration » Page TSConfig?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571309/how-to-edit-typoscript-configuration-page-tsconfig)

Comment: @MightyA Do you have a sitepackage? Meaning do you have an extension which takes care of the configuration of your TYPO3? If you do not know, where did you put your global TypoScript configuration?