# How can I rename backend labels e.g. 'author' in Typo3 and read them

Tags: typo3, typoscript

How can I rename the two backend labels 'author' and 'author_email' which you can find in the Tab 'Metadata' in edit page properties.

I tried to use the following snippets first in the template configuration and second in the Resources Tab at Page TSConfig in the page properties, emptied all caches but nothing happened:

```
TCEFORM {
tt_content {
    author.label = Teaser
}
```

}

see: [How to rename subheader in TYPO3 CMS backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094786/how-to-rename-subheader-in-typo3-cms-backend/28094788#28094788)

and this one:

```
TCEFORM.author.label.default = Teaser
TCEFORM.author_email.label.default = Sub_Teaser
```

I tried to read those fields by:

```
lib.teaser.20 = TEXT
lib.teaser.20.data = levelfield : -1 , author, slide
```

Please can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields author and author_email is attributes of table "pages", NOT "tt_content".
Please try this:
`TCEFORM {
    pages {
        author.label = Teaser
    }
}`

Comment: See documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html

Comment: Could you also let me know how to read them? I tried it like this: 

    lib.headerteaser.20.data = levelfield : -1 , Teaser, slide 

(headerteaser is my 'handmade' Gridelement) But there is still no content in the source code, only the empty wraps that I build around it.

Comment: In the template I used following viewhelper <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.headerteaser" />

Comment: Well, "lib.headerteaser" it is different problem from TCEFORM.
Please create new answer on stackoverflow, and paste your code (TS, Fluid...).

Comment: Thanks Robert! I did create a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755983/typo3-how-can-i-read-the-value-of-a-field-in-page-edit-tab-metadata/34766554#34766554