# Typo3: How can I read the value of a field in page->edit->tab: Metadata

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I create a header based on one image, one Main Header and one Sub Header.

The following fields/labels in page/edit/Metadata are renamed like that:

```
    TCEFORM.pages.author.label.default = HeaderImageMainTitle
    TCEFORM.pages.author_email.label.default = HeaderImageSubTitle
```

Now I get the content of the media/create new relation/image file and that works fine. But the values of the above two fields with former label 'author' and 'author_email' stay empty (the format tags are there, but no content):

```
lib.headerteaser = COA
lib.headerteaser.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="headerTeaser">|</div>

lib.headerteaser.10 = IMAGE
lib.headerteaser.10 {
  file {
    import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
    import.listNum = 0
  }
  wrap = |
}

lib.headerteaser.20 = TEXT
lib.headerteaser.20.data = levelfield : -1 , HeaderImageMainTitle, slide
lib.headerteaser.20.wrap = <div id="headerTeaserText"><h1>|</h1>

lib.headerteaser.30 = TEXT
lib.headerteaser.30.data = levelfield : -1 , HeaderImageSubTitle, slide
lib.headerteaser.30.wrap = <p>|</p></div>
```

The viewhelper in the template looks like that:

```
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.headerteaser" />
```

What do I miss? Studied google for hoooours!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code, works correctly (Typo3 7.6.0).

My tested Typoscript setup (without image):

```
lib.headerteaser = COA
lib.headerteaser.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="headerTeaser">|</div>

lib.headerteaser.20 = TEXT
lib.headerteaser.20.data = levelfield:-1, author, slide
lib.headerteaser.20.wrap = <div id="headerTeaserText"><h1>|</h1>

lib.headerteaser.30 = TEXT
lib.headerteaser.30.data = levelfield:-1, author_email, slide
lib.headerteaser.30.wrap = <p>|</p></div>

page = PAGE
page.10 < lib.headerteaser
```

Setup typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php:

```
<?php
return [
    ...
    'FE' => [
        'addRootLineFields' => ',author,author_email',
    ],
    ...
];
```

Plus clear Typo3 cache.

Comment: It worked out. I just wasn't sure how exactly add the rootLineFields, so I thought in Install Tool under 'addRootLineFields' I have to write '$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = ',author,author_email';' but it's only the following part ',author,author_email' without the ' '. (I tried kind of the same directly in the config and that of course then also created problems.) So thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

In .data attribute use field name, not field label:

```
lib.headerteaser.20.data = levelfield:-1, author, slide
lib.headerteaser.30.data = levelfield:-1, author_email, slide
```

And I think that You need update Typo3 configuration:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = ',author,author_email';
```

Comment: Hi Robert! Sounds logical. 
I updated Typo3 config first with Install Tool 'All Configuration' 'FE' and added your line from above. It created an uncaught exception, so I opened the 'LocalConfiguration.php' in a terminal and deleted it again - works again but didn't solve the problem...
Shouldn't those two fields already been in the 'RootLineFields'? (How can I see all included fields?)
Or do I have to use the new labels like this:
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = ',newlabel1,newlabel2';
Would be very thankful for any idea!!

Comment: So even when I rename label 'author', the field name stays 'author'? Guess it would really help to have access to this list and see the field names, but how?

Comment: You may check setting 'addRootLineFields' in Typo3 backend:  
System / Configuration / $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] - and search phrase addRootLineFields.  
Any result?  
What is TYPO3 version?

Comment: I am using 7.6.2 version. And there are no labels/fields in the above search you have mentioned. All fields I am looking for are in 'pageOverlayFields' (all: uid,doktype,title,subtitle,nav_title,media,keywords,description,abstract,author,author_email,url,urltype,shortcut,shortcut_mode).

Comment: Please see additional answer, the comment area is too short.